# A word for general proficiency with musical instruments

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a word for skill or talent with musical instruments in general.

This is for a video game, there are skills like singing and dancing and I can't put "musical instruments" because its too long.

Comment: [About single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: Singing and dancing are not "musical instruments."  Do you mean "music & dance"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is *musicianship* or *musicality*. The latter also happens to have a second, entirely different meaning, but in the context you provide it is clear which of the two you're after.

Answer (score 0):

This is not limited to musical instruments, but *virtuosity* might fit the bill.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virtuosity) defines it as "great technical skill (as in the practice of a fine art)", and adds under the "Did you know?"-section: "Virtuosity is used particularly to describe musicians, but also often for writers, actors, dancers, and athletes. A virtuoso is a highly skilled performer, and a virtuoso performance is one that astonishes the audience by its feats."

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a single word for what you want.

The shortest and most viable verb phrase I can think of is **playing music**.

(The use of just **playing** is ambiguous. Unless it's obvious from its context that it involves musical instruments, it needs to be qualified by the noun.)

Answer (score 0):

A very good option would be **music mastery**.

Though it is a bit lengthy, I believe it will pass across the effect you want,Especially in a video game.

> Welcome User! It is time to improve your **Music Mastery**.